# Input type text. Icon missing in IE

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I have HTML input box as below:

```
<input id="filter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here..." />
```

And it gets rendered as below in Chrome:
[image]

But in IE icon goes missing. I have IE10. So not sure if this icon is supported or not?
[image]

Does IE does not support bootstrap icons or I missed something here?
Cheers

Comment: I think [this](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/browsers-devices/#ie-compatibility-modes) might help you.